# Assigning Probability to cells using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I am working with the image below and I am trying to find how many pixels are in the grey corners of the image, and I want to assign them a probability of 5%. The bottom layer is my DEM and the top layer is a raster of distances. I know how many pixels I have on my raster layer, however I am not sure of how I can get the pixels outside of the circles and how to assign those pixels a probability.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps in ArcMap 10:

1. Right click on your DEM, select "Open Attribute Table".  Right click "Count" and select "statistics".  The "Sum" value is the total number of pixels in your DEM.
2. Since your rings are beyond the range of your DEM, Use Extract by
   Mask on your data, with the DEM as the mask and your Rings the input
   raster.  Make sure to use this new ring raster in your analysis.  This will ensure the final calculations are accurate.
3. Repeat step 1 with your rings and calculate the total number of
   pixels for the ring raster.
4. Say, for example, your DEM has 10,000 pixels and your ring raster
   has 7000 pixels.  From here, divide your ring pixels by your total
   DEM pixels (e.g. 7000/10000 = 0.7).

Based on this analysis, you can say there is a 0.3 probability that a randomly selected pixel within the extent of your DEM will fall outside of the rings, yet within the DEM raster (i.e. assuming the cell size is the same for both rasters).